# VueJS is asking to login every i'm open in new tab

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i wanna ask about my code, by the way, i'm really new in vue.js so, i wanna ask about this unusual behaviour i've ever meet.

When i've logged in, and then open the url in new tab, it's ask me to login again.

it's always ask me to do login every i open in new tab. am i missed something?

here is my store.js, auth.js and router.js

**store.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

import auth from "./stores/auth.js";
import user from "./stores/user.js";

Vue.use(Vuex);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        auth,
        user
    },
    state: {
        admin_id: sessionStorage.getItem("admin_id"),
        token: sessionStorage.getItem("token"),
        errors: [],
        msg: [],
        user_lists: [],
        role_lists: [],
        user_data: [],
        show_spinner: false,
    },
    getters: {
        isAuth: state => {
            return state.token != "null" && state.token != null;
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        SET_TOKEN(state, payload) {
            state.token = payload;
        },
        SET_ADMIN_ID(state, payload) {
            state.admin_id = payload;
        },
        SET_ERRORS(state, payload) {
            state.errors = payload;
        },
        SET_MSG(state, payload) {
            state.msg = payload;
        },
        CLEAR_ERRORS(state) {
            state.errors = [];
        },
        ASSIGN_USER_LIST(state, payload) {
            state.user_lists = payload
        },
        ASSIGN_ROLE_LIST(state, payload) {
            state.role_lists = payload
        },
        GET_USER_DATA(state, payload) {
            state.user_data = payload;
        },
        SHOW_SPINNER(state, payload) {
            state.show_spinner = payload;
        },
    }
});

export default store;
```

**auth.js**

```
import $axios from "../api.js";

const state = () => ({});

const mutations = {};

const actions = {
    submitlogin({ commit }, payload) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            $axios
                .post("/auth/login", payload)
                .then(response => {
                    if (response.data.status == "success") {
                        sessionStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token);
                        sessionStorage.setItem(
                            "userdata",
                            JSON.stringify(response.data.userdata)
                        );
                        sessionStorage.setItem('admin_id', response.data.userdata[0].user_id)
                        commit("SET_TOKEN", sessionStorage.getItem("token"), {
                            root: true
                        });
                        commit("SET_ADMIN_ID", sessionStorage.getItem('admin_id'), {
                            root: true
                        });
                    } else {
                        commit(
                            "SET_ERRORS",
                            { invalid: response.data.msg },
                            { root: true }
                        );
                    }
                    resolve(response.data);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    if (error.response.status == 422) {
                        commit(
                            "SET_ERRORS",
                            { invalid: error.response.msg },
                            {
                                root: true
                            }
                        );
                    }
                });
        });
    },
    submitlogout({ commit }) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            $axios
                .post("/auth/logout")
                .then(response => {
                    if (response.data.status == "success") {
                        sessionStorage.removeItem("token");
                        sessionStorage.removeItem("userdata");
                        commit("SET_TOKEN", null, {
                            root: true
                        });
                    }
                    resolve(response.data);
                })
                .catch(error => {});
        });
    },
};

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    actions,
    mutations
};
```

**router.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Router from "vue-router";
import store from "./store.js";
import Home from "./pages/DashboardPage";
import Login from "./pages/Login";
import Logout from "./pages/Logout";
import User from "./pages/User";
import UserList from "./pages/UserList";
import AddUser from "./pages/AddUser";
import EditUser from "./pages/EditUserData";
import Profile from "./pages/Profile";

Vue.use(Router);

//DEFINE ROUTE
const router = new Router({
    mode: "history",
    linkExactActiveClass: "active",
    routes: [
        {
            path: "/",
            name: "home",
            component: Home,
            meta: {
                requiresAuth: true
            }
        },
        {
            path: "/user/",
            name: "user",
            component: User,
            meta: {
                requiresAuth: true
            }
        },
        {
            path: "/user/list",
            name: "userlist",
            component: UserList,
            meta: {
                requiresAuth: true
            }
        },
        {
            path: "/user/tambah",
            name: "adduser",
            component: AddUser,
            meta: {
                requiresAuth: true
            }
        },
        {
            path: "/user/edit/:id",
            name: "edituser",
            component: EditUser,
            meta: {
                requiresAuth: true
            }
        },
        {
            path: "/profile",
            name: "edituser",
            component: Profile,
            meta: {
                requiresAuth: true
            }
        },
        {
            path: "/login",
            name: "login",
            component: Login
        },
        {
            path: "/logout",
            name: "logout",
            component: Logout
        }
    ]
});

//Navigation Guards
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
        let auth = store.getters.isAuth;
        if (!auth) {
            next({
                name: "login"
            });
        } else {
            next();
        }
    } else {
        next();
    }
});

export default router;
```

i've tried to use localStorage to store the token, but also it's seems not working.
every feedback or suggestion are appreciated. Thank You.

ps : sorry for bad english...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue. Vuex state is not persistent. So you need to install and use

`vuex-persistedstate https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persistedstate`

I hope this helps. Let me know if you have any questions.

Thanks.

Comment: okay thank you, it's working now. but, i need change the sessionStorage to localStorage to make this works. mantap gan.